# How does the contact size influence it's execution costs?

Tags: contract-development, gas

According to [this post](https://medium.com/coinmonks/optimizing-your-solidity-contracts-gas-usage-9d65334db6c7)

> The overall size of your contract will play a part in tx cost for all interactions with it.

Is that correct, and if so why?

Under that premise, is it really more efficient to split a contract into smaller ones even if it means additional interactions between those contracts?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's correct, at least directly. The tx cost of interacting with a contract is simply based on the computation it does and the storage it reads/writes. The contract size doesn't directly influence that, although more complex contracts typically mean more complex transactions as well.

Comment: Thanks, the only "explanation" I found so far was optimizations getting less optimal, but for independent functions that shouldn't happen. I'll experiment a bit to be sure but probably accept your answer then. The only thing I could imagine would be the contract size to be loaded in the EVM costing gas, but I haven't found anything on that either...